# Allow one element to inherit all events of another

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example say i have 2 links, A and B.
If a user hovers over A, the hover event of B will get triggered. Likewise with all other events like onlick, mouseover etc.

I'm not looking for adding the events manually like this:

```
$('a#A').click(function(){
  $('a#B').trigger('click');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You do know you can just join them in the selector like `$('#A, #B').on('mouseenter'...)`

Comment: @adeneo - That is still for individual elements. It wont trigger b.hover, when user hovers over a - which is what the OP seemingly is looking for.

Comment: yes but if i mouseover A, the mouseover event of B wont be triggered.

Comment: @techfoobar - There is no hover event in javascript, so even if you had dancing polarbears inside your computer you would'nt be able to trigger a hover event.

Comment: @adeneo - I meant the mouseover and out events for which jquery has given a .hover helper. I thought that was obvious enough. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with multiple events like so:

```
$('a#A').on('click mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
  $('a#B').trigger(e.type);
});
```

This will trigger any of the specified events bound on `#B`, like :

```
$("#B").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        this.style.color = "#B4B4B4";
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        this.style.color = "#000";
    }

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u4h2B/1/)

Now to make that really inefficient, lets get all the events bound to `#B` and trigger them with `#A` :

```
$("#B").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        this.style.color = "#B4B4B4";
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        this.style.color = "#000";
    }

});

var events = [];
$.each($._data($("#B").get(0), "events"), function(i, e) {
    events.push(i); //gets all events currently bound to #B
});

$('a#A').on(events.join(' '), function(e){  //and triggers them with #A
  $('a#B').trigger(e.type);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4h2B/2/)

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. I was hoping jquery would have some function call for this. but I reckon this is the most elegant solution for the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('linkDiv').each( function() {
  $('a#A').click( function() {
    $('a#B').trigger('click');}
  });
```

Use the foreach/each() jQuery function to specify that you want these two events on EVERY `<div class="linkDiv">` or `<a class="linkDiv">` you want this on. The links would look like this in your page:

```
<div class="linkDiv">
  <a class="link" id="A" href="foo.html">Foo</a>
  <a class="link" id="B" href="fap.html">Fap</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but what I meant was for all events attached to one element needs to be inherited by another

Comment: You can replicate this code ONE time in jQuery, but then lay your buttons/links out as many times as you need them. There is no "automatically generate this link x times" function in jQuery. You CAN use PHP on the server-side to generate your page contents multiple times, and that is one potential way to create more sections of links without having to write a bunch out, but then they will ALL be the same (i.e. there will be no unique URLs in &lt;a&gt;).